# LINQ Query in DataTable

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` named `dt`. It has two Columns named `atype_code` and `module`.
Now i need to query a module based on specific `atype_code`.

Here is the code i wrote but not working.

```
DataTable dt = GetATypeCodeList();
var accType = (from myAccType in dt.AsEnumerable()
           where myAccType.Field<string>("atype_code") == aTypeCode.Trim()
           select myAccType.Field<string>("module"));
```

`acctype` is a `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.String>`.

Comment: accType is showing {System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<object>}how can i get the string out of it??? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you've said that you

> need to query a module based on specific atype_code

, i assume that you want only one `module` with the given `atype_code`.

Then you should either use `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` or `First`/`FirstOrDefault`.

```
String firstModule = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(r => r.Field<string>("atype_code") == aTypeCode.Trim())
                       .Select(r => r.Field<string>("module"))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
// or
String singleModule = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Where(r => r.Field<string>("atype_code") == aTypeCode.Trim())
                       .Select(r => r.Field<string>("module"))
                       .SingleOrDefault();
```

`Enumerable.Single` throws an exception if there is more than one matching element. That can be useful to validate the data.

**Edit**:

Here's the query-syntax:

```
IEnumerable<String> modules =  
    from myAccType in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where myAccType.Field<string>("atype_code") == aTypeCode.Trim()
    select myAccType.Field<string>("module");
String module = modules.FirstOrDefault(); // returns null if no matching modules were found
```

Comment: Showing errors in Cannot convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'String'